# Why won't this code load my NIB/XIB

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I have 2 XIBs with their corresponding View Controllers. Will call them MainViewController and AboutViewController.  The names of the XIBs are exactly the same as the names of the ViewControllers.  Upon a button click in the MainViewController, I want to show the AboutViewController.

I have code like this in the MainViewController:

```
- (IBAction) infoButtonAction:(id)sender {
    AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES];
}
```

But nothing happens, the AboutViewController does not show up.  I also tried this line:

```
AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];
```

But to no avail.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Examine your AboutViewController.xib in Interface Builder and ensure that the File Owner is set to `AboutViewController` in the class inspector. Also ensure that the `view` property of the File Owner is wired into the View in the xib. Finally, the code to display it should read:

```
- (IBAction) infoButtonAction:(id)sender {
    AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES];
    [aboutViewController release];
}
```

Also, you should check that this is non-nil inside that same method:

```
UINavigationController * nc = self.navigationController;
```

Comment: You are right.  The self.navigationController is nil.  Can you tell me why and what I can do about it?

Comment: That means your MainViewController is not inside a navigationController. You will need to examine how you create your MainViewController.

Answer (score 0):

do you get an error?  Did you check that the button is correctly wired in IB?

did you try using a modal view controller?

Comment: I don't get any errors.  The button is correctly wired, because it stops on a breakpoint inside the click function.